# FFmpeg Record videos every second and save them in individual files

Tags: ffmpeg, video, v4l2

I am trying to create video every one second. I have the following code below.

It creates the first video correctly but the following does not create them correctly. Anyone know what I may be missing, it would be a great help.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -r 30 -b:v 3M -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -pix_fmt yuv420p -f segment -segment_time 1 output%03d.mp4 -y
```

Comment: Segment is not working with MP4 file format. Try `.ts` or `.flv`. Example: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -r 30 -b:v 3M -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -pix_fmt yuv420p -f segment -segment_time 1 -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.flv -y`. Using `-reset_timestamps 1` is used for starting each file from time `0` (as the question is asked it looks appropriate). Using FLV is just an example, TS files is more standard for segments, but the TS files are larger then the FLV files (few other formats are also supported).

Comment: It still doesn't work. The first fragment is ok. But the following fragments are not created correctly.

Comment: I read that this method is not so precise, it is possible to divide it every 30pfs. it would be every 1sec

Comment: Try adding `-g 30` after `h264_v4l2m2m`, and try updating the version of FFmpeg. After I added `-g 30`, it started working with MP4 files.

Comment: I have this version: ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3.4-0+deb11u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10 (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1)

Comment: I tried -g 30, but it still doesn't work for both .mp4 and .flv

Comment: The first segment is correct, but following segments when I ffprobe it, the following is output: [extract_extradata @ 0x555010] No start code is found.
output001.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Very different from when I tried the first snippet ffprobe output000.mp4 :
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output000.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand : isom
    minor_version : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1797 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1788 kb/s, 31 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name : VideoHandler

Comment: I am testing with version `version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev` in Windows 10. Test it using synthetic pattern and libx264: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1280x720:rate=30:duration=10 -c:v libx264 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f segment -segment_time 1 -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4`. FFprobe output looks fine (try it). It could be that Raspberry Pi version of FFmpeg is different (I never used Raspberry Pi).